# PHPUnit forces me to require classes before asserting instance of

Tags: php, phpunit

I am testing an object that returns an instance of another class. Internally, that class calls `require_once`. However, when I try to check that the object returned is of that type I get this message:

```
InvalidArgumentException: Argument #1 of PHPUnit_Framework_Assert::assertInstanceOf() must be a class or interface name
```

This message goes away once I call `require_once` again in my test before the call to `assertInstanceOf`. This doesn't seem right. It seems like PHPUnit should be smart enough to know that the class is already loaded, so I shouldn't have to load it again. Am I thinking of this wrong? Do I have my PHPUnit configured wrong? Is there a way to avoid requiring this class again in my test?

Comment: Is the `require_once` necessary within the class itself, or in the class' file, outside the class but loaded when the class' file is loaded?

Comment: `assertInstanceOf('MyClass')` NOT `assertInstanceOf(new MyClass)`. Make sure you're passing a string and not an instance of the class.

Comment: I am already passing a string

Comment: Is there a stack-trace with the exception message? I'm interested in knowning what PHPUnit *thinks* is being passed in as the first param. If there's not a stack-trace.. you might be able to debug some extra info out of `PHPUnit_Util_InvalidArgumentHelper` line 69'ish.

Comment: Show the code where you're doing the assertion. `instanceof` doesn't require that the class is loaded and doesn't instigate autoloading, but perhaps the method that PHPUnit employs does.

Comment: I have the same issue, here's my code:

        `$client = static::createClient();`
        `$crawler = $client->request('GET', '/');`
        `$this->assertInstanceOf('RedirectResponse', $client->getResponse());`

Comment: In my case, I have to specify the class with its namespace: `$this->assertInstanceOf('Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse', $client->getResponse());`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your unit may be similar to this:

```
$this->assertInstanceOf('MyOtherClass', 
    $this->object->someFunctionReturnsOtherClass());
```

This is alright except here, Note: phpunit method is called BEFORE your object. Since you said, your object already internally does a require_once means till your method got called, 'MyOtherClass' stays as a undefined class. Thats exactly what happened. Phpunit function prepared to check using 'MyOtherClass' and found it is undefined!

The object's own require_once never even got called. That is why you have to do a call yourself before. Its similar if you use a statement like `true == $returnObject instanceOf MyOtherClass` which will return same error since while parsing PHP failed to find the class definition.

Answer (score 29):

Be sure to use the full namespace:

```
$this->assertInstanceOf('\Namespace\Subnamespace\MyClass', $obj);
```